# Polymer route/iron-pages not working?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am just trying out Polymer 1.0. I find that `app-route`/`iron-pages` is not working. Navigating between routes does not appear to show the correct view. Not sure which part went wrong:

In the main file:

```
<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>

  <app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:view"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

  <app-drawer>
    <main-drawer></main-drawer>
  </app-drawer>

  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div class="title">
          Expenses App
        </div>
      </paper-toolbar>

      <iron-pages selected="[[view]]">
        <expenses-dashboard name="dashboard" route="{{subroute}}"></expenses-dashboard>
        <expenses-settings name="settings" route="{{subroute}}"></expenses-settings>
      </iron-pages>
    </app-header>
  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

In side both `expenses-dashboard` and `expenses-settings` is just placeholder content like:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="expenses-dashboard">
  <template>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'expenses-dashboard'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

For `<iron-pages selected="[[view]]">`, should I be using `routeData.view` or `view`? I tried both didnt seem to change anything.

The code on **[GitHub](https://github.com/jiewmeng/polymer-expenses/tree/3aec3c81cec083e08ff962880bf4aae1b3f1bd1b)**

Comment: `routeData` is a dictionary that can contain multiple items. So you should use `<iron-pages selected="[[routeData.view]]">`

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues in your code...

1. Since your `<iron-pages>.selected` property is bound to an undefined property ("view"), `<iron-pages>` does not change its page. In your `<app-route>` data binding, the route parts are parsed into `routeData`, where the `:view` slug would be accessed with `routeData.view`, which is what you should be binding to `<iron-pages>.selected`:

   ```
   <iron-pages selected="[[routeData.view]]">
   ```
2. The default selector for `<iron-pages>` is the page index (i.e., the child index of its contents), so `selected` would normally have to be an integer between `0` and `N - 1` inclusively, where `N` is the number of child pages. But you could change that. It looks like you want the route to specify the page, which would need to match the name of a page under `<iron-pages>`. To use `"name"` as the selected attribute, you'd have to configure [`<iron-pages>.attrForSelected` property](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#property-attrForSelected):

   ```
   <iron-pages selected="foo" attr-for-selected="name">
     <div name="foo"></div>
     <div name="bar"></div>
   </iron-pages>
   ```

   It might also be a good idea to specify a [fallback selection](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#property-fallbackSelection), since the user could accidentally navigate to a URL that doesn't correspond to an existing page (e.g., `https://mypage.com/#/non-existent-page`).

   ```
   <iron-pages selected="[[routeData.view]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="foo">
     <div name="foo"></div>
     <div name="bar"></div>
   </iron-pages>
   ```
3. In `<main-drawer>`, you may want to define [`menuTap()`](https://github.com/jiewmeng/polymer-expenses/blob/3aec3c8/src/expenses-app/main-drawer.html#L26) with ES5 syntax (instead of ES6) for maximum browser compatibility.

   ```
   Polymer({
     // menuTap(e) { ... }  // <-- ES6
     menuTap: function(e) { ... }
   });
   ```
4. Your `menuTap()` function sets the `window.location` to a raw path, which noticeably refreshes the page. You could avoid the page refresh by using hash paths, where the intended sub-path of the URL is prefixed with a `#` (e.g., `https://mypage.com/#/settings`).

   For hash paths, configure `<app-location>` to ignore the hash prefix by setting the [`useHashAsPath` property](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-route?active=app-location#property-useHashAsPath):

   ```
   <app-location use-hash-as-path route="{{route}}">
   ```

   If you prefer to avoid hash paths, you could follow Polymer CLI's `app-drawer-template`, which uses anchor tags inside an `<iron-selector>` to set the location, which `<app-location>` detects and updates its `route` accordingly. Or you could pass the `route` in from `<expenses-app>` and then use `this.set('route.path', "dashboard")` inside of `menuTap()`.

With the changes above, the following would occur when the user navigates to `https://mypage.com/#/dashboard`.

1. `<app-location>` would set the `route` property to `/dashboard`.
2. `<app-route>` would parse the `route` and set `routeData.view` to `dashboard`.
3. `<iron-pages>` sees `routeData.view` as `dashboard`, which matches the specified attribute on a child, which in turn causes only that page to be displayed.

For reference, the guide on [*Encapsulated Routing with Elements*](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/routing) is quite useful.